# Setting back the original locale does not work

Tags: java, locale

I get the original locale,  save it, then set it back. But the JVM does not set as expected.

```
BigDecimal bdNumber = new BigDecimal(10000.23);

Locale initLocale = Locale.getDefault();

System.out.println("Original locale: " + initLocale);
System.out.println(bigDecimalToString(bdNumber));

Locale.setDefault(initLocale);

Locale newLocale = Locale.getDefault();

System.out.println("New locale: " + newLocale);
System.out.println(bigDecimalToString(bdNumber));
```

Helper method:

```
    public static String bigDecimalToString(BigDecimal number) {
    DecimalFormat myFormatter;
    myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00");
    return myFormatter.format(number);
}
```

Output:

```
Original locale: en_US
10 000,23
New locale: en_US
10,000.23
```

Why is that? How to properly set the original locale, so that the BigDecimal output is "10 000,23"?
The question is more about properly setting locale rather than manipulating BigDecimal formatter.

Comment: What are you setting your locale too.  The code does not match the output (at least when I run it).  I get the same `10,000.23` for both.

Comment: I am setting to the original value.